# Google Business Profile Api for Php Library

Tags: php, api

```
$this->accounts = new Google_Service_V1_MyBusiness_Accounts_Resource(
      $this,
      $this->serviceName,
      'accounts',
      array(
        'methods' => array(
          'get' => array(
            'path' => 'v1/{+name}',
            'httpMethod' => 'GET',
            'parameters' => array(
              'name' => array(
                'location' => 'path',
                'type' => 'string',
                'required' => true,
              ),
            ),
          ), 'list' => array(
            'path' => 'v1/accounts',
            'httpMethod' => 'GET',
            'parameters' => array(
              'parentAccount' => array(
                'location' => 'query',
                'type' => 'string',
```

**Google Business Profile for Php library**
I need to understand in this php library source code 'path' => 'v1/{+name}', I see this kind of sytanx. I need someone to explain how {+name} works. I don't understand how bracket is using in this array.Thank you

Comment: Is this just some example code from a documentation page? If so, please give us a link to it. At a guess, you're probably supposed to replace the `{+name}` with a real value that you want to use in your code. It's not PHP syntax that, it's just a value inside a string.

Answer (score -1):

By the looks of it, it is a placeholder for matching a url.

So when I would execute a GET request to /api/v1/someEndpoint it is matched to the 'get' method that you have declared.